# Proving Markov–Lukacs theorem from SOS programming

Tags: polynomials, optimization, convex-optimization, positive-semidefinite, sum-of-squares-method

Let $f(t)$ be a univariate polynomial of *even* degree $n$.

**Markov-Lukacs theorem** ([reference](https://www.seas.ucla.edu/%7Evandenbe/publications/nnp.pdf),Eq.45) says this:

$f(t)$ is nonnegative in $t\in[-1,1]$ iff
$$
f(t)=g(t)^2+(t+1)(1-t)h(t)^2
$$

where $g$ and $h$ are polynomials with $\operatorname{deg}(g) \leq n/2$ and  $\operatorname{deg}(h) \leq (n-2)/2$.

**SOS programming** ([reference](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-972-algebraic-techniques-and-semidefinite-optimization-spring-2006/lecture-notes/lecture_10.pdf), Theorem 6) says this:

$f(t)$ is nonnegative in $t\in[-1,1]$ iff
$$
f(t)=s(t)+(t+1)(1-t)q(t)
$$

where $s$ and $q$ are SOS polynomials with $\operatorname{deg}(s)\le n \text { and }\operatorname{deg}(q)\le n-2 $.

---

My question is: How could the first theorem be proven using the second one?

Note that, according to Exercise 3.30 of [link](http://www.mit.edu/%7Eparrilo/sdocag/SIAMBookFinalvNov12-2012.pdf), a univariate nonnegative polynomial can be expressed as a sum of **two** squares.

Thanks!

Comment: No to both questions: an SOS decomposition is not unique. So you can always obtain $s$ and $q$ from $g$ and $h$ (trivially) but not the other way around.

Comment: What information are you looking for in addition to my comment?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @LinAlg! I guess I'm still confused about this: As Markov-Lukacs theorem holds, that means that g(t) and h(t) exists for a given f(t). Hence, we could take s(t) and q(t) as the squares of these polynomials. But this means that there will always exist a SOS decomposition of s(t) (or q(t)) that only has one square. But then, why are two squares needed for some SOS univariate polynomials? 

In other words. it seems that Markov-Lukacs theorem is a much stricter version of the other theorem, since only polynomials that are sum of one square are allowed.

Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, I think I understood it better with this example:
$$\quad$$
$f(t)=\underbrace{(t+1)^{2}+(t+2)^{2}}_{:=s(t)}+(t+1)(1-t)\underbrace{(t+3)^{2}}_{:=q(t)}$
$\qquad=(\underbrace{-1.37t^{2}+1.303t+3.672}_{:=g(t)})^{2}+(t+1)(1-t)(\underbrace{1.696t+0.7169}_{:=h(t)})^{2}$
$$\quad$$
I guess the question is then if it is possible to prove the first theorem from the second one (just edited the question). Thanks!